# Тестирование html

Tags: html, веб-программирование, тестирование

Как протестировать обычную страницу?
В чем должно заключаться такое тестирование и что можно использовать для этого?
Имеется только ее адрес и все.

Comment: смотря что Вы от тестирования хотите

Comment: что подразумевается под тестированием?

Comment: Наверное правильность написания кода

Comment: А затестить можно в браузере, например хроме (разные разрешения доступны + сможете прям в нем поменять что то в коде и наглядно это увидеть). Есть интернет сервисы для проверки сразу несколькими браузерами и разными версиями.

Comment: На странице имеется форма для ввода данных о себе(имя, фамилия, номер телефона, адрес почты)
Я так понимаю ее можно протестировать на корректность вводимых данных?

Comment: Вам валидация нужна что ли? Тестирование - это проверка того, что готовая программа работает правильно. А валидация проверяет, что пользователь ввел нужные данные.

Answer (score 1):

Тестировать вэб-ресурс, в частности отдельную страницу, можно по многим параметрам. Попробую навскидку перечислить основные направления проверки.

```
1) Валидация корректного написания кода;
2) Прверка на битые и не правильные ссылки;
3) Ошибки контента, в первую очередь граматические;
4) Уникальность контента и копирайты;
5) SEO-аудит, который сам по себе включает множество пунктов контроля;
6) Кросбраузерность и адаптивность страницы;
7) Удобство восприятия и взаимодействия со страницей (юзабилити);
8) Оценка безопасности ресурса;
...
```

Наверно, можно придумать что-то ещё. По каждому пункту проверки существует множество сервисов, выполняющих подобный аудит. Пока Вы не уточните, что конкретно Вы хотите тестировать, ответить будет затруднительно.